# How to get HTML from a current request, in a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a report that I generate with HTML.

I'd like to get the HTML output of the page, and be able to send it via email. I'm having problem with session, because the report redirect me to the login page because when I create a new WebRequest, it doesn't use the information of the current session.

Is there a way to get the HTML of the report without having to code a work-around for the security ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This code get the job done

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter htmlTW = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

RenderControl(htmlTW);

string html = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: No it will give a error "A page can have only one server-side Form tag."